# How to set new parameter to adb shell pm list features?

Tags: android, shell, adb

Help me please
I am a developer of a test automation system, making a system for testers. I would be grateful for your help

Displayed my parameters like this:

```
x86_64: / # pm list features
feature: reqGlEsVersion = 0x0
feature: android.hardware.ethernet
feature: android.software.freeform_window_management
feature: android.software.live_wallpaper
feature: android.software.webview
```

how I can to set new such parameters?

I want to set a parameter for example, there are still others, but for example I give one

```
feature: com.google.android.feature.En
```

how to do it?

I was looking for how to do it via adb - I did not find it

Actions were taken:
I tried to set it in build.prop, but it didn't work

when run **adb shell pm list** features my parameter did not load

I was looking for options with adb commands, I could not find anything except the command how to display the parameters

```
pm list features
```

but how to set them is not clear